# grails db-migration dbm-update command failure

Tags: postgresql, grails, grails-plugin, database-migration

I am using grails 2.4.2 and postgresql with grails db-migration 1.4.0 plugin. Whenever I issue the grails dbm-update command I get the following exception thereby resulting in failure of tables creation:

```
    Starting dbm-update for database user @ jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb
liquibase.exception.LockException: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Empty result set, expected one row
    at liquibase.lockservice.LockService.acquireLock(LockService.java:121)
    at liquibase.lockservice.LockService.waitForLock(LockService.java:61)
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:102)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1_closure2.doCall(DbmUpdate:26)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure2_closure11.doCall(DbmUpdate:59)
    at grails.plugin.databasemigration.MigrationUtils.executeInSession(MigrationUtils.groovy:133)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure2.doCall(DbmUpdate:51)
    at DbmUpdate$_run_closure1.doCall(DbmUpdate:25)
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Empty result set, expected one row
    at liquibase.util.JdbcUtils.requiredSingleResult(JdbcUtils.java:124)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:159)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:167)
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.queryForObject(JdbcExecutor.java:163)
    at liquibase.lockservice.LockService.acquireLock(LockService.java:96)
    ... 7 more
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This looks like Liquibase wasn't initialiezed properly. Check if you have a row in the table `DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK`

Comment: I think I have found the answer. Before issuing the command I used to drop both DATABASECHANGELOG and DATABASECHANGLOGLOCK tables, and this caused the above mentioned issue. Once I just dropped the DATABASECHANGELOG such that the DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK still contained one row
and the command worked fine. Anyways thanks for your hint.